# Distance from $f(0)$ to the boundary of $D$ if $f$ maps open unit disk to $D$ conformally

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a conformal map from the open unit disk onto $D$, which is a domain.

I would like to show that the distance from $f(0)$ to the boundary of $D$, denoted $\partial D$, is given by $\mathrm{dist}(f(0), \partial D) \le |f'(0)|$, that is, it is bounded by $|f'(0)|$.

What is a good way to approach this?

I believe the Schwarz lemma might be of help. It says: Let $f(z)$ be analytic for $|z| < 1$. Suppose $|f(z)| \le 1$ for all $|z| < 1$ and $f(0) = 0$. Then $|f(z) \le |z|$ for $|z| < 1$. If equality holds for some point $z_0 \ne 0$, then $f(z) = \lambda z$ for some constant $\lambda$ of unit modulus.

Is this belief correct? Also, how would the proof be finished in its entirety?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $R= d(f(0),\partial D).$ Define $g(z) = f(0)+Rz.$ Then $g$ maps the open unit disc onto $B(f(0),R)\subset D.$ Consider $f^{-1}\circ g.$

Comment: Why does $f^{-1}$ exist?